# How to properly submit, create and populate new information from my HTML to Javascript to the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express

My question is, I am trying to preform a javascript function that will use a HTML prompted modal that is using an input text field and a radio button selection followed by a submit button. How can I take my commands from my modal and push the info to the back-end and then get it to display on the browser side?

```js
const baseUrl       = "http://localhost:3001/"
let quotaValue      = document.getElementById('newQuota').value
let difficultyValue = document.querySelector('#difficulty2').value
const addBtn        = document.getElementById('addBtn')

const openButton  = document.querySelector('[data-open-modal]')
const closeButton = document.querySelector('#cancel')
const modal       = document.querySelector('#modal')
const outputBox   = document.querySelector('output')
const inputEl     = modal.querySelector('input')
const easyBtn     = document.querySelector('data-easy-button')
const mediumBtn   = document.querySelector('data-medium-button')
const hardBtn     = document.querySelector('data-hard-button')

const createQuotaForm = document.getElementById('create-quota-form')

// // ==== ADD-MODAL LOGIC ==== //

openButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.showModal()
})

addBtn.addEventListener('click', async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('click')
  console.log(quotaValue, difficultyValue)
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}goals`, {
      title: quotaValue,
      level: difficultyValue
    })
    console.log('Goal created:', response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error creating goal.', error)
  }
})

addBtn.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // modal.close(inputEl.value)
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload()
  }, 1000)
})

closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.close()
})
```

```html
<button data-open-modal type="button" class="primary-button shadow-main circle"><img src="../images/plus.svg"></button>


<dialog id="modal">
  <div class="modal-title">Set up a new Quota</div>
  <form action="http://localhost:3001/goals" method="POST" id="create-quota-form">
    <div>
      <label for="newQuota" class="newQuota">New Quota: </label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new task" name="text-field" class="newQuota" id="newQuota" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="difficulty">Quota difficulty</div>

    <div class="difficulty-btns">
      <input type="radio" id="difficulty1" class="diff" name="difficultyBtn" value="(50 pts)">
      <label for="difficulty1" class="label label-1">Easy (50 pts)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="difficulty2" class="diff" name="difficultyBtn" value="100">
      <label for="difficulty2" class="label label-2">Medium (100 pts)</label>

      <input type="radio" id="difficulty3" class="diff" name="difficultyBtn" value="(150 pts)">
      <label for="difficulty3" class="label label-3">Hard (150 pts)</label>
    </div>
    <button id="cancel" value="cancel" formmethod="dialog">Cancel</button>
    <button id="addBtn" value="Add Quota">Add Quota</button>

  </form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? You're already sending a request using Axios. Why not use the response to update the UI?

Comment: The thing is, I'm still new to coding, I was trying something that is evidently fairly advanced in comparison to where I currently am. I would like to take the text entered by a user and the selection they choose, and then create a new "tile" or "block" displaying that info on screen.

Comment: Submitting on a `<form>` involves loading a new page on the browser.
otherwise with `<dialog>` as parent you must use `<form method="dialog">` and send your data by ajax. you have to choose either change pages or use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this...

```js
const
  Btn_Dialog  = document.querySelector('#bt-open-dialog')
, modalDialog = document.querySelector('#modal-dialog')
, modalForm   = modalDialog.querySelector('form')
  ;
Btn_Dialog.onclick =_=>
  {
  console.clear();
  modalForm.reset();
  modalDialog.returnValue = null;
  modalDialog.showModal();
  }
modalForm.btCancel.onclick =_=>
  {
  modalDialog.close();
  }
modalDialog.onclose =_=>
  {
  if ( modalDialog.returnValue === 'OK' )
    console.log( 'JSO for Axios', Object.fromEntries( new FormData(modalForm)) );
  else
    console.log( 'canceled, no data to add!' );
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
#bt-open-dialog {
  font-size        : 2rem;
  color            : #fff;
  font-weight      : bold;
  border           : none;
  line-height      : 2rem;
  width            : 3rem;
  height           : 3rem;
  border-radius    : .4rem;
  cursor           : pointer;
  background-color : darkcyan;
  caret-color      : transparent;
  }
#bt-open-dialog:hover {
  color            : #f5be0a;
  background-color : #1d9191;
  }
dialog {
  border-radius : 1rem;
  min-width     : 31rem;
  }
dialog::backdrop {
  background: #ff00225d;
  }
dialog h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
dialog > form > label {
  display   : block;
  margin    : 0.8em;
  font-size : .9rem;
  }
fieldset > label {
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-right : 1em;
  }
input:not([type=radio]) {
  display    : block;
  }
dialog button {
  margin-top   : 1rem;
  margin-right : 1rem;
  width        : 29%;
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-open-dialog">+</button>

<dialog id="modal-dialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <h2>Set up a new Quota</h2>
    <label>
      New Quota: 
      <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter new task" value="" required >
    </label>

    <fieldset>
      <legend> Quota difficulty </legend>
      <label> <input name="level" type="radio" value="(50 pts)" required >  Easy (50 pts) </label>
      <label> <input name="level" type="radio" value="(100 pts)"> Medium (100 pts) </label>
      <label> <input name="level" type="radio" value="(150 pts)"> Hard (150 pts) </label>
    </fieldset>

    <button value="OK">Add Quota</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" name="btCancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```